# doClick() in KeyListener compilation issue

Tags: java, compiler-errors, classpath

I have such a class KeyListener but when you want to compile a program in this class gives me an error:

`Error: can not find symbol`

```
class MyKeyListener implements KeyListener{

        Program applet;
        MyButton button;
        MyKeyListener(Program applet, MyButton button){
            this.applet = applet;
            this.button = button;
        }

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_0) {
                    button.doClick();
            }
        }
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
    }
```

Comment: Could you put the import section of this file and also the definition of MyButton?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely that error message means that IDE (or Java compiler) is unable to find one of your classes - `KeyListener`, `Program`, `MyButton` or `KeyEvent`. To fix that, you have to add all these classes (or its `jar` files) into the classpath.

See [Javac vs Java within -classpath option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15121697/javac-vs-java-within-classpath-option)